# Server side error Selective repeat in s.cpp

Tags: c++, network-programming, g++, redhat, network-protocols

Following is the link of my code where I am trying  to do ther transfer using selective repeat in s.cpp aka server but I am getting following errors. I tried alot but I am not able to get rid of the errors. I would really very very appreciate if please anybody can help me on this and get the code running. Everything is present regarding the code and details in the following zipped folder. Kindly help.

http://ge.tt/#!/19q29ug1/v/0

For s.cpp ERRORS:

```
In file included from unp.h:7,
from s.cpp:1:
config.h:2:22: warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive
s.cpp:31: warning: alignment must be a small power of two, not 1000
s.cpp:52: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘while’
s.cpp:60: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
s.cpp:65: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘while’
s.cpp:69: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
s.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
s.cpp:140: error: ‘udp_checksum’ was not declared in this scope
s.cpp:161: error: ‘l’ was not declared in this scope
```

**S.cpp complete code:**

```
#include "unp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#define MYPORT 10101


#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
socklen_t len;
int sockfd;
int n;


using namespace std;
ofstream out;
ofstream logout;
time_t mytime;

void handler(int a)
{
    logout<<"Exiting..."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    close(sockfd);
    out.close();
    logout.close();
    exit(0);
}

#pragma pack(1000)   // this helps to pack the struct to 5-bytes
struct pkt
{
    int seq_no;
    int ack_no;
    char segment[BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint16_t checksum;
    pkt()
    {
        ack_no=0;
    }

};

#pragma pack(0)   // turn packing off
struct pkt reciv;
struct pkt data[8];// = new pkt;
struct pkt ack; // = new pkt;
struct pkt ackwindow[8];


    while (len > 1)
    {
        sum += *buf++;
        if (sum & 0x80000000)
            sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
        len -= 2;
    }

    if ( len & 1 )
        // Add the padding if the packet lenght is odd          //
        sum += *((uint8_t *)buf);

    // Add the carries                                              //
    while (sum >> 16)
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

    // Return the one's complement of sum                           //
    return ( (uint16_t)(~sum)  );

void copy(pkt&a,const pkt b)
{
    a.seq_no=b.seq_no;
    a.ack_no=b.ack_no;
    a.checksum=b.checksum;
    memcpy(a.segment,b.segment,BUFFER_SIZE);
}
//--------------------------------------------- Main -----------------------------------------//

int rdt_recv()
{
    return 1;
}
int N=8;

//--------------------------------------------- Main -----------------------------------------//

int main()
{
    logout.open("reciver_logfile.txt", ios::out);
    signal(SIGINT,handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP,handler);
    signal(SIGQUIT,handler);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    memset(server_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero) );

    //------------------------------------------------------//

    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof server_addr);
    //cout<<endl;

    perror("bind");
    out.open("file2.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
    //------------------------------------------------------//
    struct timeval tv;

    tv.tv_sec = 5;  /* 4 Secs Timeout */            //        See Reference
    tv.tv_usec = 0;  // Not init'ing this can cause strange errors


    int recv_status,send_status;

    int counter = 0;

    size_t data_size=sizeof(data[0]);

    len = sizeof(sockaddr);

    int seq = 0;            //        expected sequence number
    int iteration = 0;


    int i=0;

    int expected_seq_no=0;
    int check=0;
    while(true)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        memset(reciv.segment, 0, sizeof(reciv.segment));
        recv_status = recvfrom(sockfd, & reciv, data_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &len);
        reciv.ack_no=0;
        if(strcmp(reciv.segment,"kill")==0)
            kill(getpid(),SIGINT);
        cout<<udp_checksum(reciv.segment,BUFFER_SIZE)<<" : "<<reciv.checksum<<endl;

        if(udp_checksum(reciv.segment,BUFFER_SIZE)==reciv.checksum && expected_seq_no==reciv.seq_no)
        {
            copy(data[expected_seq_no%N],reciv);
            data[expected_seq_no%N].ack_no=1;
            logout<< ctime(&mytime)<<"                        packet number: "
            <<data[expected_seq_no%N].seq_no<<" recived."<<endl;

            cout<<"\n\naccepted seq no: "<<reciv.seq_no<<"\n"<<endl;

            data[expected_seq_no%N].segment[recv_status-(sizeof(data[expected_seq_no%N])-BUFFER_SIZE)]='\0';
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                cout<<data[i].seq_no<<": "<<data[i].ack_no<<endl;
            }
            int pkt_written=0;
            if(data[0].ack_no==1&&check==7)


                int l = 0;
                while (data[l].ack_no == 1)
                {

                    if (data[l].ack_no != 0)
                    {
                        seq = data[l].seq_no;
                        data[l].ack_no = 0;
                        cout << "-------------------writing packet number " << data[l].seq_no << endl;
                        for (int k = 0; k < (recv_status - (sizeof(data[expected_seq_no%N]) - BUFFER_SIZE)); k++)
                        {
                            out << data[l].segment[k];
                        }
                        pkt_written = pkt_written+1;
                    }
                    check = 0;
                    l = l + 1;
                }

                int k = 0;
                while (k < pkt_written)
                {
                        int i = 0;
                        while (i < N)
                        {

                            copy(data[i], data[i + 1]);
                            i = i + 1; 
                        }

                    data[N - 1].ack_no = 0;
                    k = k + 1;
                }

            cout<<"\n------------------------------------------------------"<<expected_seq_no<<endl;

                int i = 0;
                while (i < N)
                {

                    cout << data[i].seq_no << ": " << data[i].ack_no << endl;
                    i = i + 1;
                }

            reciv.ack_no=1;
            cout<<reciv.seq_no<<" got it!"<<endl;

            expected_seq_no++;
            reciv.seq_no=expected_seq_no;
            check++;

        }
        else
        {
            reciv.ack_no=1;
            logout<< ctime(&mytime)<<"                        packet corrupt: "
            <<reciv.seq_no<<endl;
            cout<<reciv.seq_no<<" send again"<<endl;
            reciv.seq_no=expected_seq_no-1;
        }

        if(rand()%100<5)
            sleep(4);
        memset(reciv.segment, 0, sizeof(reciv.segment));

            send_status = sendto(sockfd, &reciv, sizeof(reciv), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, len);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg kindly take a look only in the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this block of code from line 52 to 69

```
while (len > 1)
    {
        sum += *buf++;
        if (sum & 0x80000000)
            sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
        len -= 2;
    }

    if ( len & 1 )
        // Add the padding if the packet lenght is odd          //
        sum += *((uint8_t *)buf);

    // Add the carries                                              //
    while (sum >> 16)
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

    // Return the one's complement of sum                           //
    return ( (uint16_t)(~sum)  );
```

They are just invalid